# MIPS: Calculator print string not executing with syscall; Prompt 1 not printing after a single calculation

Tags: string, assembly, long-integer, mips32

I'm working on a calculator in MIPS that can support long integers. The calculation ends up fine, however when I try to print the result, the syscall for printing a string doesn't actually print anything. The result ends up getting printed after the system loops and the syscall for the first prompt is executed. When I debug it and go step by step, it shows that the system does get to the execute line, however nothing happens after it does execute.

I'm having a bit of trouble nailing down exactly what is causing it. I'm thinking it has to do with my getInput procedure where I read a string.

Here are the procedures I think may be an issue.

```
#Procedure:  GetInput
#Displays a prompt to the user and then wait for a numerical input
#The users input will get stored to the (word) address pointed by $a1
#Input: $a0 points to the text string that will get displayed to the user
#Input: $a1 points to a word address in .data memory, where to store the input number
getInput:
    #PRINT STRING
    li      $v0, 4              #Load print string syscall
    syscall                    #Execute

    #READ INPUT
    move        $t0, $a1         #Save pointer
    li          $v0, 8          #Load read string input
    li          $a1, 80
    syscall                    #Execute
    move        $a1, $t0         #Reload pointer

    #SAVE RETURN TO STACK
    addi $sp, $sp, -4            #Subtract 4 to stack to prevent loss of memory
    sw $ra, 0($sp)               #Saves #ra on stack

    #CONVERT
    jal     DecAscToBin        #Jump to convert ascii to binary

    #LOAD RETURN FROM STACK
    lw $ra, 0($sp)               #Loads $ra on stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4             #Add 4 to stack to prevent loss of memory

    jr      $ra             #Return
```

DisplayNumb:

```
#Procedure: DisplayNumb
#Displays a message to the user followed by a numerical value
#Input: $a0 points to the text string that will get displayed to the user
#Input: $a1 points to a word address in .data memory, where the result value is stored
displayNumb:
    #PRINT STRING
    li      $v0, 4              #Load print string syscall
    syscall                     #Execute

    #SAVE RETURN TO STACK
    addi $sp, $sp, -4               #Subtract 4 to stack to prevent loss of memory
    sw $ra, 0($sp)                  #Saves #ra on stack

    #CONVERT RESULT BINARY
    move        $a0, $a1            #Load pointer of result to be converted in $a0
    la      $a1, buffer         #Load pointer of result buffer for holding string to be printed in $a1
    jal     BinToDecAsc         #Convert

    #LOAD RETURN FROM STACK
    lw $ra, 0($sp)                  #Loads $ra on stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4                #Add 4 to stack to prevent loss of memory

    #PRINT RESULT
    la      $a0, buffer             #Copy result into $a0
    li      $v0, 4              #Load print string syscall
    syscall                     #Execute <-- RUNS BUT NOTHING PRINTS

    jr      $ra             #Return
```

[image]

This might not be enough information to solve the problem on it's own. You can grab the whole project from my the Github page [here](https://github.com/JmTexas19/mipscalc/tree/longint). The project is located in mipscalc.asm.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is that I was using the string for prompt 1 to read in a string from the user. If I use a new buffer string to read in the input instead, it solves the issue.

```
#READ INPUT
    move        $t0, $a1         #Save pointer
    la          $a0, buffer      #LOAD BUFFER STRING INSTEAD OF PROMPT STRING
    li          $v0, 8           #Load read string input
    li          $a1, 80
    syscall                      #Execute
    move        $a1, $t0         #Reload pointer
```